# Selecting elements using two lists

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, filtering

I made the following list:

```
ELCo = Alphabet["English"];    
Characters[ToLowerCase[WordList[Language -> "English"]]];
Select[%, SubsetQ[ELCo, ToLowerCase[#1]] &];
LPr = Map[Sort, Map[DeleteDuplicates, %]];
```

This list `LPr` takes the English words and separates them into their characters while getting rid of duplication and capital letters. Now I make another list, basically the first five letters of the English language:

```
letters = Alphabet[][[1 ;; 5]];
```

Now I want to look at `LPr` and select all those words that are made of letters `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, `"d"`, or `"e"` or the combination of them. 
I wonder how one would to this, I tried:

```
tmp = Table[SubsetQ[letters, LPr[[i]]], {i, Length[LPr]}];
```

and then,

```
Pick[LPr, tmp]
```

but this does not give me all those required words.

Comment: `LPr` does not contain any reference to original words anymore so what exactly is a desired output? Words or your `LPr` entires?

Comment: `LPr` enteries that contains  `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, `"d"`, or `"e"` or the combination of them.

Comment: I tried different approach and I get exactly what your `Pick` returns. So I guess you should explain why do you think your result is not correct.

Comment: If you run `LPr` you see for instance the second entry is `{"a","h"}` this element has `"a"` but was not picked.  As I mentioned I need the return to contain contains `"a"` or  `"b"` or `"c"` or `"d"` or `"e"` or the combination of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
Select[ ContainsAny @ CharacterRange["a", "e"] ] @ LPr
```

> {<<36k>>}